# How to edit and delete data in yaml-cpp?

Tags: yaml-cpp

I have, so far, successively emit and view data from yaml file, but I can't modyfy it. I did try to overwrite sth, but it didn't work. For deleting, I thought that I can load whole file to a variable, and then using std::string and regexp, procces it, and send it back, but it's not satisfactory, clean or "nice". What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean "overwrite sth"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly with yaml-cpp; your best bet is to read it into your own data structure, modify that data, and then emit it.